# Changing element sequence dynamically in XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, apache-fop

I am using JAXB to generate xml from JavaBean. I need to change order of element dynamically so can't use `propOrder`.

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"ele1", "ele2"})
```

I am open to any other xml generation solution to fix this.

I feed this xml to Apache FOP. ..say i am creating file 1. it starts with  but still there is some data for file2.  sO next xml I need is ...now say in file2, I am unable to accommodate  , Next xml needs to be ....Its like simple chapters in a book.

related

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491395/generating-large-pdf-using-fop

Comment: Why do you need to change the order dynamically?

Comment: It's like I generate xml for for page.. I need to change order of element based on that. I feed this xml to Apache FOP. Say I am printing <tableType1> and half of it goes to file2, I have to generate next xml as <tableType1><tableType2> ...if my file 3 is half I need xml like <tableType2><tableType1>